# Организация приложения AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Я новичок в AngularJS. Задача сделать приложение, которое при запуске будет начинать собирать данные(например, координаты движения мышки), а затем передавать его их в разные котроллеры (например, один будет считать скорость, другой собирать статистику, на каких координатах мышь была больше всего раз)
В связи с этим не могу понять, как организовать структуру приложения. 
Большой скрипт, который нужен мне рабочим с начала и до конца приложения запихивать в сервис и к каждому контроллеру добавлять его в зависимость?

Или подгружать этот скрипт в шапке, делать переменные координат мыши глобальными и внутри каждого контроллера их отлавливать?

Comment: Вы для начала определитесь, что будете использовать - angularJS или angular 2? К томе же, зачем тут ангулар?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko
 добрый день. Использую AngularJS 1.3.15. А использование ангуляра это поставленная задача, не моя прихоть

Comment: Тогда можете создать директиву, которая будет следить за мышкой и обновлять данные в сервисе. В контроллерах инжектите этот сервис и получаете из него данные.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо за ответ, но как я понял из туториала, директива создается для вставки html участка кода в нужное место index.html. У меня же есть скрипт на почти 10к строк, который собирает для меня необходимые данные, эти данные я бы хотел получать на каждой страницы angularJS приложения(использую роутинг), т.е. чтобы они были доступны в каждом контроллере из этого роутинга

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. Директива нужна, потому что в директивах нужно привязываться к событиям передвижения мыши. Можете, конечно, сделать и компонент, смысл особо не поменяется.